# Django get data from second model filtered by values from the first

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have these two models:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(blank=True)
    desc = models.TextField(blank=True) 
    address = models.TextField(blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    reservation_date = models.DateField()
    event_participant = models.IntegerField(blank=False,default=0)

class Reservation(models.Model):
    event_id = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

When I list all my events, I wan to calculate the rest of possible participant.
So I tried it in my view:

```
def events_list(request):
    events = Event.objects.all().order_by('date')
    #I started here
    for event in events:
        obj = Reservation.objects.filter(event_id=event)

    return render(request, 'events_list.html', {'events': events, 'obj': obj})
```

But the obj is empty.
Or is there a better way to calculate the participant (participant - quantity)?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean in this sentence:  `I wan to calculate the rest of possible participant` ?@beli3ver

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must add `related_name` in your `Reservation` model and also rename `event_id`:

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='reservation_events')
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Then in your view you can use this `query`:

```
events = Event.objects.all().order_by('date')
objects = Reservation.objects.filter(reservation_events=events)
```

**Hope this answer has helped.**